# Verifying JAVA signature in php

Tags: java, php, rsa, sha1, phpseclib

Its been a day now that I am stuck on this. I looked around a lot but was unable to resolve the issue.

**JAVA Code:**

```
public String generateDigitalSignedToken(String requestData) throws Exception 
{
    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
    PrivateKey privateKey = this.readPrivateKeyFromFile(busPrivateFile);
    signature.initSign(privateKey, new SecureRandom());
    byte[] message = requestData.getBytes();
    signature.update(message);
    byte[] sigBytes = signature.sign();
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(sigBytes);
}
```

**PHP Code:**

```
$rsa = new RSA();
$rsa->loadKey($publicKey);
$rsa->setSignatureMode(RSA::SIGNATURE_PKCS1);
$rsa->setHash("sha1");
$rsa->setEncryptionMode(RSA::ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);
$receivedHash = $rsa->decrypt($decodedHash);
```

**TODOS**

1. Decrypt the token to get the received hash.
2. The second task is to re-create the hash and compare it with the received hash.

**Code to re-create the hash**

```
$temp = new RSA();
$temp->setHash('sha1');
$temp->setSignatureMode(RSA::SIGNATURE_PKCS1);
$generatedHash1 = $temp->hash->_sha1($decryptedBody);

//Or simply

$generatedHash2 = sha1($data, true);
```

> Following are the values :
>
> "receivedHash" => b"0!0\t\x06\x05+\x0E\x03\x02\x1A\x05\x00\x04\x14**öRM▀ÿuï®▀Q÷Å\x06M¬Õ\x16{M^**"
>
> "generatedHash1" / "generatedHash2" => b"**öRM▀ÿuï®▀Q÷Å\x06M¬Õ\x16{M^**"

As can be seen, the hash matches partially even when the same strings were used on both ends.

Can anyone please help me resolve this issue?
I would appreciate any help.

**EDIT:**

PHP library used: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib

Comment: We don't know what PHP RSA library you're using.

Comment: Hello @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk, have updated the question, please check.

Comment: That library appears to be undocumented, which in my opinion is a good reason not to use it. However, I would expect the RSA object has a `verify` method that should be used for signatures instead of the `decrypt` method. And don't set the encryption mode either as it either has no effect or else it breaks your code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The library does have a `verify` method but the hash received is encrypted, so to get the hashed string I have to first decrypt it.

Comment: Also, the generated hash is the same even when I used `sha1($data, true);` this method. The problem is it matches partially with the received one.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk - the library has documentation at http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/

Comment: For reproducibility purposes it'd help if you posted `$publicKey` and `$decodedHash`

Comment: @neubert: All I see there are a very few examples that don't show much. I don't even see an example that shows the methods of RSA. You have to look at the source code to figure out what's available.

Comment: @vivektakrani: No, the hash is *signed*. See the Java code. You need to use the PHP `verify` method. At least try it and see what happens.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk - I don't know what you're talking about. http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/rsa/intro.html (which is linked to on the index) has hyperlinks to each of the features. Click on them and you'll see plenty of examples.

Comment: @neubert: I don't what you're talking about. Click on the link that says "Create/Verify signatures PKCS#`1". It shows exactly one method, the rsa createkey method, and no others. And anyway, a handful of examples is not documentation.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk - no it doesn't. Here's the link that it takes me to: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/rsa/examples.html#sign,sign2 I see four methods: `loadKey()`, `setSignatureMode()`, `sign()` and `verify()`.

Comment: @neubert: That's not what I get when I click on that link. All I see is the createkey method.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk - I see what's going on. When you selected the version you're using you selected 2.0. I selected 1.0 since that's what it defaulted to. If you go into Incognito mode and select 1.0 you'll see what I was seeing. Overall, it looks like a bug. I'll submit a bug report. But as for whether or not that software should be used...  it's the most downloaded crypto library for PHP with 50,000,000+ downloads on packagist and is what PEAR recommends people use for RSA.

Comment: @neubert: Yes. Is 1.0 what is commonly used?

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk - according to packagist it's 2.0 that's most commonly used. You selected the right version - I did not lol. I'll try to submit a bug report later tonight!

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk - it looks like it's working better now! Might have to refresh your cache!

Comment: Hello @neubert - I have even tried using the `verify` method it throws 'Invalid Signature' Error.

Comment: @vivektakrani - they're not interchangeable. Anyway, like I said earlier, can you post the public key you're using and the signature / plaintext that you're trying to verify? If I can reproduce the problem I can play around with it myself instead of having you try a bunch of things. Help me help you!

Comment: @neubert - Can you provide me your email id? I will share it over there or any other closed channel that you prefer.

Comment: Hello @neubert, sent, please check.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that "receivedHash" isn't *just* a hash. It's a hash wrapped in an ASN.1 structure. If you do openssl asn1parse on it you'll get the following:

```
    0:d=0  hl=2 l=  33 cons: SEQUENCE
    2:d=1  hl=2 l=   9 cons:  SEQUENCE
    4:d=2  hl=2 l=   5 prim:   OBJECT            :sha1
   11:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim:   NULL
   13:d=1  hl=2 l=  20 prim:  OCTET STRING
```

You can get the actual sha1 hash (in PHP) by doing this:

```
substr(base64_decode('MCEwCQYFKw4DAhoFAAQUlFJN35h1i6nfUfaPBk2q5RZ7TV4='), 13 + 2, 20)
```

There are other arguably better ways to do this that actually parse the ASN.1 and "map" it but those are more verbose and that's beyond the scope of this "answer" anyway.

Another problem is that `receivedHash` isn't the actual signature nor is it a valid ciphertext. Your RSA key is 2048 bits. That's 256 bytes. Both the signature / ciphertext should be that length as well. Sure, I suppose it could be smaller if you trimmed leading or trailing NULL space but, even then, the signature / ciphertext shouldn't have "structure" to it like yours does. Maybe prior to the modular exponentiation it would but not after. So I think a lot of the issue is probably in your Java code. Maybe when I get home I can run your Java code locally and see if I get a similar output to your `receivedHash`. If so I can make my own stackoverflow post asking what's up with that. But for the time being I'd look at your Java code.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, will wait for your findings on Java code.

Comment: @vivektakrani - in your Java code you have `PrivateKey privateKey = this.readPrivateKeyFromFile(busPrivateFile);`. Is that a function you've defined? Could you generate a new private key in the format that that method is expecting? Maybe I could generate a key in the right format myself but it'd be more convenient if you could do so. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @neubert, 
Sorry for replying late, I was able to fix the issue. In my PHP Code, there was no need to decrypt the body before verifying the hash. I simply had to decode it, generate hash on my end and verify.